# Getting error when doing Enable-Migrations in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to create 1:many relationship between Person and Car.
I know this is trivial. But on passing a `Enable-Migrations` in package manager console i am getting this:

> Car_Person_Target_Car_Person_Source: : The types of all properties in
>   the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the
>   corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of
>   property 'PersonID' on entity 'Car' does not match the type of
>   property 'FirstName' on entity 'Person' in the referential constraint
>   'Car_Person'.
>
> Car_Person_Target_Car_Person_Source: : The types of all
>   properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be
>   the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role.
>   The type of property 'PersonSsn' on entity 'Car' does not match the
>   type of property 'LastName' on entity 'Person' in the referential
>   constraint 'Car_Person'.

Person Class:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Cars = new List<Car>();
    }
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int Ssn { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }  
}
```

Car class:

```
public class Car
{        
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ChassisSerial { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int? PersonID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Person"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int? PersonSsn { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Change the type of the foreign keys to "int", they must match with Person's PK type

```
public class Car
{        
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ChassisSerial { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Person"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PersonSsn { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using composite key, you should use Fluent API from Entity Framework, to configure the relationships. For example:

Person Configuration

```
public class PersonEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => new { t.ID, t.Ssn });
        Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

Car Configuration

```
public class CarEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
    public CarEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => new { t.ID, t.ChassisSerial });
        Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasOptional(t => t.Person).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => new { t.PersonID, t.PersonSsn });
    }
}
```

And in your Context class, you register in `OnModelCreating`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{ 
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonEntityTypeConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CarEntityTypeConfiguration());

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: I know that fluent API might be a solution. But, I am using this above for an Odata Web API. And I don't know how to use fluent API there.

Comment: Its Infrastructure Layer responsibility, if you are using Layered Project. But anyway, you can create a folder "Configuration" in your project, and put EntityTypeConfiguration classes in there, and in your Context class, you register those classes, as the code above.

Comment: @Ankit what you have decided?

Comment: Hi @Pedro, The issue asked in question was due to using both fluent api and data annnotation and settting different properties as Key. I had simplified and changed the names for clarity. As per your comment i meant to ask [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557511/how-do-you-get-a-web-api-odatamodelbuilder-to-work-with-ef-fluent-api-mappings). Do you know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue when looked at the context class.

The issue was due to already existing composite key FirstName-LastName defined in context class using both car and person `as DbSet`.

> Car_Person_Target_Car_Person_Source: : The types of all properties in
>   the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the
>   corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of
>   property 'PersonSsn' on entity 'Car' does not match the type of
>   property `LastName` on entity 'Person' in the referential constraint
>   'Car_Person'.